# Cordova vibration plugin not working

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, cordova-plugins, vibration

I have tried everything my device is not on mute but vibration plugin seems to be not working:

```
 (function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

    function onDeviceReady() {

        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
        document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );
        document.getElementById("vibrate").addEventListener("click", vibrate);
        document.getElementById("vibrationPattern").addEventListener("click", vibratePattern);
        // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
        var parentElement = document.getElementById('deviceready');
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    };


    function vibrate()
    {
        var time = 3000;
        navigator.vibrate(time);
        alert('vibrate(v1) ');
    }
    function vibratePattern()
    {
        var pattern = [1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000];
        navigator.vibrate(pattern);
        alert('Pattern');
    }
})();
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
HTML
/////////////

```
<button id="vibrate">VIBRATION</button>
<button id="vibratePattern">PATTERN</button>
```

Comment: that plugin's build is failing... which means it doesn't work an they already know it doesn't work. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-vibration/

Comment: @DavidDanielyan Not necessarily a failing build means the plugin is not working. The build failure may be due to issues with CI too. Check out this link - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-vibration You could see that the build is passing in AppVeyor. Have you includes cordova.js in your HTML? Also look for any error in device console using chrome inspector

Comment: I am using visual studio I included all of the javascript code in index.js